# importer which imports .py files only

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I need a Python http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/ finder and importer class which works on a specific directory, but it can load only `.py` files (i.e. no `.so`, no `.dll`, no `.pyc`).

The specified directory contains several packages (with `__path__` specified and overridden from the default `__path__` added for `__init__.py`).

Also I need a loader which doesn't create `.pyc` files, and doesn't use any of the Python 2.6-specific solutions (e.g. `sys.dont_write_bytecode = True`, `python -B` or `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`).

Comment: You could always load the files and use compile()/exec directly.

Comment: I know about compile and exec, but the modules I want to load have complicated inter-dependencies (they are importing hundreds of each other), and I'd like to get exactly the same import filename resolution as Python has, but without loading any non-`.py` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find an existing implementation, I wrote one: https://github.com/pts/import_only_py/blob/master/import_only_py.py